# getting only integer from an input field

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, database, integer

Lets say i'm trying to obtain a phone number from an input field which uses jquery. This jquery automatically populates the input with () and - so it'll be able something like (123) 234-1234. So I would like to insert only the numbers into mysql database and not have `()-`

Can someone help me out here?

Thank you

Comment: why not just use a regex pattern to strip out non number characters?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
$number = preg_replace('/[^0-9]/', '', $input);
```

Should give you just the numbers. This will not validate it though.